# Convert from encoded unicode String into Java String

Tags: java, unicode

I have a string in json data which looks like this:

```
#0023Sat Apr 30 10:46:11 UTC 2016#000a[Interoperability]Interoperability#005c Index=Unknown (R03)#000a[Exif]Shutter#005c Speed#005c Value=1/1999 sec#000a[Exif]Bits#005c Per#005c Sample=8 8 8 bits/component/pixel#000a[Exif]Exposure#005c Bias#005c Value=0 EV#000a[Exif]Sub-Sec#005c Time#005c Original=00#000a
```

All those #XXXX words are unicode.

How do I convert this into a Java String?

Comment: Standard JSON uses `\uXXXX` to escape Unicode values, not `#XXXX`. Any JSON parser should be able to handle `\uXXXX` automatically. If your JSON really contains `#XXXX` instead, then 1) it is not standard JSON, and 2) you will have to parse it manually to decode the characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("#([0-9A-Fa-f]{4})");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    int c = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1), 16);
    m.appendReplacement(sb, String.valueOf((char) c));
}
m.appendTail(sb);
return sb.toString();
```

This assumes that #XXXX encodes a UTF-16 Unicode code point. Unicode code points actually supercede the 16 bit range of #XXXX.

Comment: Instead of `StringBuffer`, you could use `StringBuilder` for better performance.

Comment: In standard JSON, Unicode characters are encoded using UTF-16 codeunits in `\uXXXX` format, where non-BMP codepoints use UTF-16 surrogates in `\uXXXX\uXXXX` format. So assuming this non-standard `#XXXX` syntax follows similar rules, this code will decode BMP and non-BMP codepoints just fine, since Java strings and characters use UTF-16 anyway.

Comment: @FrankPuffer StringBuilder is indeed newer and faster, however [Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) only works with `StringBuffer`.

Comment: Interesting that... the appendReplacement could have take the super class of both - AbstractStringBuilder and I don't think be any side effect.

Comment: @JoopEggen thanks for the solution, I was thinking something like that would be what I need